# Inverse search in xsim with Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, forward-inverse-search, xsim

I can't get `xsim` to get along with `TexStudio`'s inverse search (Ctrl left-clicking in the live preview brings up the corresponding source code). The problem is that when I left-click in a given exercise in the the live preview window, `TexStudio` brings up the corresponding auxiliary file (*-exercise-body.tex) generated under the hood by `xsim` instead of the actual source file I wrote. Is there any workaround for this? Actually, this used to work fine for me, but a recent update to `TexStudio`, which forced me to delete all the settings, raised the issue. However, I also tried with Kile and I have the same problem. Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: See https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/issues/9

Comment: It's good to know...thanks for the heads up!!